# Publishing Related Items from Experience editor

Tags: experience-editor, publishing

We are using Sitecore 9.0.2 and SXA and we are allowing Authors to create and publish pages using Experience editor. A component takes Datasource of "Datasource-Folder" with X numbers of "Datasource-Item" below.

The tree looks like this:
Datasource

Item1

Item2

Item3

Item4

Now the issue is in the Experience Editor the user can edit the Datasource Item's fields, i.e. he can edit image, text, general link field of this Datasource Item and Doesn't matter if they choose `Smart publish` or `Republish` Items are not getting published. We have also tried checking both `Publish subitems` and `Publish related items`. None of it works. If we then go into the Content Editor, we can see that the fields are changed correctly, and if we do a publish from the Content Editor, the changed are correctly published to the Web database

I have seen many blogs online but none of them points to actual solution . Can somebody help.

**Additional Information:** **Tried below steps in new Sitecore 9.0.2 with SXA and without any custom code**

- If Content Author will add any item in the Content tree (not in Datasource tree) and update Experience Editor > Partial Design >Page List component
  content item and then use Experience Accelerator > Publish > Site option, then it will publish all items from content tree and **changes reflecting in Web db**.
- If Content Author will update Experience Editor > Partial Design >Page List component
  content item and then use Experience Accelerator > Publish > Current Page option, then **it's not showing updated item in Web db**.
- If Content Author will update Experience Editor > Partial Design >Page List component
  content item and then use Experience Accelerator > Publish > Site Partial Design option, then **it's not showing updated item in Web db**.
- If Content Author will update Experience Editor > Partial Design >Page List component
  content item and then use Home > Publish option, then **it's not showing updated item in Web db**.
- If Content Author will update item directly via Content Tree and then use Home > Publish option, then **it's showing updated item in Web db**.

[image]
Reference: https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/8/t/1210

It seems to be issue with Sitecore Product. Anyone also faced this issue earlier and any inputs?

Comment: If you publish from the content editor, what publish do you perform? (which parent and which options)

Comment: Please add the update the main question

Comment: Issue is there  from experience editor if i publish from content tree i just say Smart Publish Item with Related Stuff

Comment: I created a custom workflow with code that loops through all the datasource items and as appropriate publish the child items. It's a double edged sword that to the content author it seems like they're just modifying a single page even though it's made up of components with child/related datasource items.

Answer (score 0):

As per Sitecore Support Team, Publishing of items for the PageList component not supported in the EE and it's expected behavior :

This conclusion is based on the following facts:

1. The items for the Page List components are taken dynamically based on the chosen Source Type (this logic is defined in `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.RenderingVariants.Repositories.ListRepository` class).
2. You can change the Source Type any time what change the current output of this component.
3. Moreover, you can choose a custom query which will render any possible item that you choose.
4. There is no actual relation between the Page List components and items which it shows.

Suggestion to make item non-editable by disabling the option.

Steps to Disable Edit functionality for Rendering Variant Field:

1. Go to your Rendering Variant item.
2. Select particular Field
3. Search `Is editable` option (It's present inside the Variant Details).
4. Un-check the `Is editable` option. After this open the Partial
5. Design where PageList component and verify it will not allow to edit particular field for which Is editable option un-checked.